# heapq only returns one smallest element and repeats in n times

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
l = l.tolist()
print l
a =map(lambda n: (n, l.index(n)), heapq.nsmallest(10, l))
print a
```

I am supposed to get n smallest values and get their indices as well. This is what my list l looks like:

```
[0.0, 1.2539001654836799, 1.4142135623730951, 1.3658846339193351, 1.4142135623730951, 1.281152234379981, 1.099505153652233, 1.2192825978417745, 1.3070322617798436, 0.816496580927726, 1.220751561539038, 1.0399514929428215, 0.5665577237325317, 1.3070322617798436, 1.4142135623730951, 1.2635083249417993, 1.24580461402113, 0.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.335753012765126, 1.4142135623730951, 1.224744871391589, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.0720400531735916, 1.3527260161829606, 1.4142135623730951, 1.2245268482707887, 0.0, 1.3949866143877465, 1.1379806676741042, 1.4142135623730951, 0.0, 1.2174217778114313, 1.236881782228955, 1.4142135623730951, 1.1355702929632454, 1.2191171936752918, 0.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.1126864258529479, 1.2457126474432216, 1.063177502732622, 1.3946856448190905, 1.224744871391589, 0.40406101782088427, 0.0, 1.0543103186130183, 1.1799747563113012, 1.3462319864066854, 0.4714045207910318, 1.4142135623730951, 1.224744871391589, 1.3402597868683133, 0.0, 0.0, 1.224744871391589, 1.3628014677755116, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4112268892528592, 1.169995251652283, 0.0, 1.2565915096888973, 1.1139079148978197, 1.4142135623730951, 1.3759915742008493, 1.0752906583803283, 1.2503307690911658, 1.4142135623730951, 1.1620244517419938, 0.7811805524688614, 0.0, 1.2747548783981961, 1.224744871391589, 1.3695092389449426, 1.4142135623730951, 1.2148162604743167, 1.225981149281404, 1.2884098726725126, 1.4142135623730951, 1.1995962825976847, 0.925526876973327, 0.0, 1.4142135623730951, 0.0, 0.690459273174666, 1.402947692127912, 1.0945758864544817, 1.092906420717, 0.42426406871192857, 1.0367154533334184, 1.4142135623730951, 1.2999081666672145, 1.4142135623730951, 1.276302885399521, 1.2965359077630336]
```

And this is the value of a:

```
[(0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0), (0.0, 0)]
```

It is just taking the first minimum value and repeating it 10 times.

Edit: The problem is not with heapq but rather with list.index(). 0 is occurring multiple times but it is only returning the first index each time

Edit: Question: How to find indices given a value duplicated at multiple positions in a list?

Comment: This has *nothinig* to do with `heapq`. The problem is that `list.index` returns the index of the first occurrence of the element. Since you have many `0.0` values `heapq` obviously returns an array of 10 `0.0` values and `list.index` always return the index of the first occurrence of `0.0`, i.e. `0`. If you don't want duplicates you should first remove them: `my_list = list(set(l))` then use `heapq` and `list.index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension along with enumerate to get the indexes in your output rather than use map

```
import heapq
l=[0.0, 1.2539001654836799, 1.4142135623730951, 1.3658846339193351, 1.4142135623730951, 1.281152234379981, 1.099505153652233, 1.2192825978417745, 1.3070322617798436, 0.816496580927726, 1.220751561539038, 1.0399514929428215, 0.5665577237325317, 1.3070322617798436, 1.4142135623730951, 1.2635083249417993, 1.24580461402113, 0.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.335753012765126, 1.4142135623730951, 1.224744871391589, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.0720400531735916, 1.3527260161829606, 1.4142135623730951, 1.2245268482707887, 0.0, 1.3949866143877465, 1.1379806676741042, 1.4142135623730951, 0.0, 1.2174217778114313, 1.236881782228955, 1.4142135623730951, 1.1355702929632454, 1.2191171936752918, 0.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.1126864258529479, 1.2457126474432216, 1.063177502732622, 1.3946856448190905, 1.224744871391589, 0.40406101782088427, 0.0, 1.0543103186130183, 1.1799747563113012, 1.3462319864066854, 0.4714045207910318, 1.4142135623730951, 1.224744871391589, 1.3402597868683133, 0.0, 0.0, 1.224744871391589, 1.3628014677755116, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4112268892528592, 1.169995251652283, 0.0, 1.2565915096888973, 1.1139079148978197, 1.4142135623730951, 1.3759915742008493, 1.0752906583803283, 1.2503307690911658, 1.4142135623730951, 1.1620244517419938, 0.7811805524688614, 0.0, 1.2747548783981961, 1.224744871391589, 1.3695092389449426, 1.4142135623730951, 1.2148162604743167, 1.225981149281404, 1.2884098726725126, 1.4142135623730951, 1.1995962825976847, 0.925526876973327, 0.0, 1.4142135623730951, 0.0, 0.690459273174666, 1.402947692127912, 1.0945758864544817, 1.092906420717, 0.42426406871192857, 1.0367154533334184, 1.4142135623730951, 1.2999081666672145, 1.4142135623730951, 1.276302885399521, 1.2965359077630336]

for index,element in heapq.nsmallest(10,enumerate(l),key=lambda  x: x[1]):
    print (element,index) ,
```

OUTPUT

```
(0.0, 0) (0.0, 17) (0.0, 29) (0.0, 33) (0.0, 39) (0.0, 48) (0.0, 56) (0.0, 57) (0.0, 63) (0.0, 73)
```

Comment: I had to untick your answer. You can see the indices they are just from 0-9. However, 0 doesn't occur in those places in the list

Comment: @FatimaArshad Sorry I misunderstood your question, I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on previously posted answer this is what I have done:

```
elements = heapq.nsmallest(10,l)

a = [(element,index) for index,element in enumerate(l) if element  in elements ]
```

These are the indices:

```
[(0.0, 0), (0.0, 17), (0.0, 29), (0.0, 33), (0.0, 39), (0.0, 48), (0.0, 56), (0.0, 57), (0.0, 63), (0.0, 73), (0.0, 84), (0.0, 86)]
```